# Mongoose - add or update a subdocument with findoneandupdate and $push (when upsert is true)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to create an array of subdocuments with specific condition. If `ip` `agent` and `language` fields are all the exact match then there is no need to add a new subdocument, and if any of them decsent then I need to create a new one.

But when I try to do it with `$push` it returns me

```
Exception: StrictModeError: Path "ip" is not in schema, strict mode is `true`, and upsert is `true`.
```

`findOneAndUpdate` updates the whole document and my fields set as they appear in the database. Also tried to set it as it appears in the Schema but it returns the same error.

Array in **userSchema**

```
metadata: [mongoose.modelSchemas.UserMetaData],
```

**userMetaDataSchema**

```
  var userMetaDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    ip: { type: String, default: '' },
    agent: { type: String, default: '' },
    language: { type: String, default: '' },
    userCreated: {
      id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      name: { type: String, default: '' },
    }
  });
  app.db.model('UserMetaData', userMetaDataSchema);
};
```

If I try to use `findOneAndUpdate` straightforward to `UserMetaData` collection without `$push`, it works.

The result from console:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a00d35f03fc3eb63cbb1c6f"),
        "agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0",
        "ip" : "::ffff:192.168.33.10",
        "language" : "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "userCreated" : {
                "name" : "user2",
                "id" : ObjectId("5a00d27a7fdf8e07f40d2123")
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
```

The query that is not working

```
    var fieldsToSet = {
      $push: {
        metadata: {
          agent: userAgent, 
          ip: userIp,
          language: languages, 
          userCreated: {
            name: req.user.username,
            id: req.user._id,
          }
        }
      }
    };
    var options = { upsert: true };

    User.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, fieldsToSet, options, function(err, user) {....
```

What is the preferable way for creating such array? Thank you.

Comment: `metadata: [mongoose.modelSchemas.UserMetaData],` is just outright wrong. What is your intention here. 1. To **embed** an array of metadata within the `User` model? 2. To **reference** metadata objects in their own collection within the `User` model? You seem really confused on the difference since you are mixing techniques of the two. Perhaps you should show how you want your documents stored, and I mean show ALL the relevant parts since even the query conditions here likely do not match what you think they are matching.

Comment: In the boilerplate I had it was the way to save subdocuments. I don't wanted to overload the document with all the data and still leave it as a boilerplate (I have 4 more embeded arrays). So I had 2 options - set expire, but then I have to refactor all the code from embed to refs because TTL indexes are not supported with embedded arrays, or to create only unique entries. If I use it without $push it doesn't appear in the document. I am really not sure about this. What's the right way to do it when you referencing a lot of bits of info for some document? Maybe it still worth  refactoring?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When someone leaves a comment on your question, the usual reason is because your question needs clarification and therefore requires you to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47148415/edit) and clarify ( supply more information ) on the parts you were explicitly asked to. Which means instead of believing you are "engaging in a conversation" you instead show the details you were requested to **in your question** and not make long winded comments in response. Comments don't tell us anything. Show the relevant parts of schema and documents as requested

Comment: I have added an example af desirable output - visits field and full query

Comment: How does this correspond to your schema definitions? Explain yourself! One statement is attempting to push to `metadata`, then you say you want `visits`!! What does a `User` actually look like? No schema for that here. Explain what the `metadata` schema is supposed to look like. If you cannot clearly present your case then you don't get a correct answer. Try to remember that we are not sitting at your computer and can only see what you actually show us. Again [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47148415/edit)

Comment: You have userMetaDataSchema in the question. a part from user schema related to it too. I don't realy understand what code are you talking about? visits its just for understanding of another schema embedded similar way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158368/discussion-between-asem-and-neil-lunn).

Answer (score 3):

The error here was caused by trying to use `findOneAndUpdate`with `$push` and `{upsert: true}` option because if you want to insert or update a **subdocument** you should do this with 2 different operators `$set` for updating and `$push` for inserting. So the solution here is to use  different setups for update and insert:

```
    var conditions = {
      _id: req.user._id,
      'metadata.ip': userIp,
      'metadata.agent': userAgent, 
      'metadata.language': userLanguage, 
      'metadata.userCreated.name': req.user.username
    };
    var fieldsToSet = {
      $set: {
        'metadata.$.agent': userAgent, 
        'metadata.$.ip': userIp,
        'metadata.$.language': userLanguage,
      }
    };
    var fieldsToPush = {
      $push: {
        metadata: {
          agent: userAgent,
          ip: userIp,
          language: userLanguage,
          userCreated: {
            id: req.user._id,
            name: req.user.username,
          }
        }
      }
    };
    var options = { upsert: true };
    // check if thare is a match and overwright
    User.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, fieldsToSet, options, function (err, setdocs) {

      //if there is no match then push a new subdocument
      if (setdocs == null) {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, fieldsToPush, function (err, pushdocs) {
         //...
        });
      }
      else {
        //....
      }
    });
  });
```

The credit to this solution goes to [Neil Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn) I just cant find this particular solution right now

Comment: Thanks, I had $push and it should be $set. Thanks for pointing this out!